# Excel VBA - Project Resets after UserForm is called via Worksheet_Change event

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with a Worksheet_Change event that calls a sub in a module. The worksheet_change code is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim itemType As String, material As String, size As Variant, rating As Variant, weldType As String
Dim rowNum, i, iMax, j As Double

If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
Disable_Slowdowns

'....code for other columns which is not triggered....

    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.row > 4 Then
         If Len(Target.Value2) > 0 Then AutoFill_By_PN Target
    End If
Enable_Slowdowns
End Sub
```

Code for the Enable_Slowdowns and Disable_Slowdowns subs, stored in a module:

```
Sub Disable_Slowdowns()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub

Sub Enable_Slowdowns()
    If Application.EnableEvents = False Then Application.EnableEvents = True
    If Application.ScreenUpdating = False Then Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Then, the sub doing the work, called AutoFill_by_PN (a variable is declared outside of the sub, within the module, called selectedPartIndex):

```
Public selectedPartIndex As Integer

Public Sub AutoFill_By_PN(ByVal rngPN As Range)
Dim vCell As Variant
Dim wb, costingWB As Workbook
Dim strTemp, PN, sName, sPrice, sSize, sType As String
Dim quotePosR, spacePosL, counter, i, k As Integer
Dim priceL, priceR As Variant
Dim dict As Object

Disable_Slowdowns
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
PN = rngPN.Value2
Set costingWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="Z:\Shared\Materials\Parts Book\New Parts Book - Official.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=1, ReadOnly:=1)
counter = 0
selectedPartIndex = -1

For Each vCell In wb.Sheets("PARTS BOOK").Range("$F$260:$F$3872")
    With vCell
        If InStr(1, .Value2, PN, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            sName = "name" & counter
            sType = "type" & counter
            sPrice = "price" & counter
            sSize = "size" & counter
            dict.Add sName, .Value2
            dict.Add sType, .Offset(, -2).Value2

            quotePosR = InStr(1, .Value2, """", vbTextCompare)
            If quotePosR > 0 Then
                spacePosL = InStrRev(.Value2, " ", quotePosR, vbBinaryCompare)
                strTemp = Evaluate(Replace(Mid(.Value2, spacePosL + 1, quotePosR - spacePosL - 1), "-", "+", compare:=vbTextCompare))
                dict.Add sSize, strTemp
            Else
                dict.Add sSize, ""
            End If

            priceR = .Offset(, 3).Value2
            priceL = .Offset(, 2).Value2
            If IsNumeric(priceL) And IsNumeric(priceR) Then
                If priceL - priceR <= 0 Then
                    dict.Add sPrice, priceR
                Else
                    dict.Add sPrice, priceL
                End If
            ElseIf IsNumeric(priceL) Then
                dict.Add sPrice, priceL
            ElseIf IsNumeric(priceR) Then
                dict.Add sPrice, priceR
            Else
                dict.Add sPrice, ""
            End If
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    End With
Next vCell
If counter - 1 <= 0 Then
    With rngPN
        .Offset(, 3).Value2 = dict(sName)
        .Offset(, 4).Value2 = dict(sType)
        .Offset(, 6).Value2 = dict(sSize)
        .Offset(, 13).Value2 = dict(sPrice)
    End With
Else
    For i = 0 To counter - 1
        UF_PartSelection.LB_PartList.AddItem dict("name" & i), i
    Next i
    UF_PartSelection.Show
End If

If selectedPartIndex >= 0 Then
    With rngPN
        .Offset(, 3).Value2 = dict("name" & selectedPartIndex)
        .Offset(, 4).Value2 = dict("type" & selectedPartIndex)
        .Offset(, 6).Value2 = dict("size" & selectedPartIndex)
        .Offset(, 13).Value2 = dict("price" & selectedPartIndex)
    End With
End If

Enable_Slowdowns
End Sub
```

The idea is that a part number is entered in a cell, then the parts book is searched and some values are populated in other columns. The important part is that sometimes the part number is found within text for multiple parts, at which point a userform is shown that lets the user select the correct part. The form is showing and all involved code runs without errors until the very last line (literally), when the worksheet_change code reaches "End Sub" - then I get a message that "this action will reset the project".

Why is this happening? Code for the userform below (fields populate correctly and the chosen item is captured correctly)

```
Private Sub cmd_ok_Click()
Dim i, indexNo As Integer, vItem As Variant
indexNo = -1
For i = 0 To Me.LB_PartList.ListCount
    If Me.LB_PartList.Selected(i) = True Then indexNo = i
Next i
If indexNo >= 0 Then capture_ListBox_Index indexNo Else capture_ListBox_Index -1
Unload Me
End Sub
```

And the code to capture the listbox selection, in the same module as the AutoFill_by_PN sub:

```
Public Sub capture_ListBox_Index(indexNo As Integer)
    selectedPartIndex = indexNo
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. I can't seem to identify what action is specifically triggering the project reset - it happens on the "End Sub" line in the worksheet_change code each time when I step through the code in debugging mode.

[EDIT]: I have found that the code runs fine when there is only one matching part number. This leads me to believe it must have something to do with the userform code because the userform is only shown when there are multiple matches. Additionally, the cell values are all updated correctly according to the part selected by the user in the userform, even when I get the "Project must be reset" message. Very strange.

[EDIT 2]: I tried running this code in the AutoFill_By_PN sub and still have the same problem:

```
If counter - 1 <= 0 Then
    With rngPN
        .Offset(, 3).Value2 = dict(sName)
        .Offset(, 4).Value2 = dict(sType)
        .Offset(, 6).Value2 = dict(sSize)
        .Offset(, 13).Value2 = dict(sPrice)
    End With
Else
    Dim ui As New UF_PartSelection
    For i = 0 To counter - 1
        ui.LB_PartList.AddItem dict("name" & i), i
        ui.LB_PartList.List(i, 1) = FormatCurrency(dict("price" & i), 2)
    Next i
    ui.Show
End If
```

[EDIT 3]: Thank you for the comment. After rewriting the code inside the "else" block shown above, the problem is solved! Code below:

```
Else
    Dim ui As UF_PartSelection
    Set ui = New UF_PartSelection
    For i = 0 To counter - 1
        ui.LB_PartList.AddItem dict("name" & i), i
        ui.LB_PartList.List(i, 1) = FormatCurrency(dict("price" & i), 2)
    Next i
    ui.Show
End If
```

Comment: Tried that, same problem - see EDIT 2

Comment: `As New` has nasty side-effects you'll also want to avoid.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not sure what side effects you mean but the problem is solved when I rewrite the code without using `As New`

Comment: `As New` creates an auto-instantiated object, which means it's always going to be a valid object reference. `Set thing = Nothing` will destroy the object, and then doing `thing.Show` will re-created it and happily run the member call. Or, merely doing `If thing Is Nothing Then` will also re-create it. `As New` is almost always a terrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, even though I don't understand it at all. For some reason, having the VBE window open is causing the project to be reset when the worksheet_change sub terminates. Closing the VBE window eliminates the problem. Anyone know why that is? I've never encountered anything like this before.

Comment: Normally the form designer closes when the code is running. This still looks very much like a form default instance problem.

Comment: Mathieu - you were right. My solution was a workaround but yours is an actual solution. Thank you for your help!